# Reducing the search space before solving an asymmetrical AP with hungarian algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm solving a scheduling problem where I want to assign a number of tasks to the fewest number of employees possible. Each task has a predefined start time, so I start with the earliest tasks of the day, assign them to employees, and update that employee's available time. I repeat this loop to see if a task can be assigned to an already used employee. If it can, then I calculate a cost & put it in an AP matrix. If it can't, I bring on a new employee. As you can guess, with each iteration, the number of employees goes up as the number of unassigned tasks approaches 0.

The heuristic works great as is, but it takes awhile. This is because, for example, If i have 400 tasks, of which 5 cannot come after another task, that first round has 5 employees & 395 tasks to assign to those 5 employees. To solve this, I pad the matrix so my hungarian algorithm has a 395x395 matrix for an input. The second round is a little better since there might be 25 employees & 375 remaining tasks, etc...

My question is: how can I safely reduce the search space? For example, when I have 395 tasks & can only pick 5, I should be able to limit the search space to only the cheapest, say, 10% of trips. The thought I had was to go through each employee & "guess" which task would it would end up receiving (based on min cost). If that "guess" was already used by a previous employee, choose the next best option for each. I think this might work, but my math isn't great so I can't prove it to myself that this wouldn't affect the outcome. I'm also unsure how to adapt this when the number of unassigned tasks becomes smaller than the number of used employees. Any guidance would be great!

Answer (score 2):

One sound approach to reducing the search space when you have N employees to assign is to only include the cheapest N jobs for each employee.

To see that this is enough, consider a solution where Alex is assigned to a job which is not in the cheapest N.  In this case, there must be at least one cheaper job to assign Alex to (because at most N-1 can be occupied by the other workers), so this cannot be the optimal solution.

Note that it may well happen that there is considerable overlap in the cheapest jobs for the different people - this is fine and just means that the search space is reduced even more.  (e.g. if we have 3 employees and all 3 like the same 3 jobs, then we only need to search over these top 3 jobs.)

When the number of assigned tasks is smaller, you can do the same logic in reverse, if there are K tasks, then just keep the cheapest K employees for each task.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I wonder, how could I further improve this? For example, assume I have 3 employees & 100 jobs. If all 3 employees had 3 discrete jobs, that'd result in a 9x9. However, given the 3 jobs for each are discrete, I know I can reduce the search space to 3x3.

Comment: Good point - there is certainly still more scope for optimisation. I can't think of a straightforward approach that would be easy to code at the moment.  However, I do wonder if it will actually help.  My guess is that in such cases the assignment algorithm will actually work very efficiently already.

Comment: After lunch I thought of one possibility: For each employee, make an array of top N jobs. Add each job to a dictionary, if it already exists, increment the value by 1. For each key in the dictionary, if the value is 1 & that is the first choice for an employee, remove both the employee & job from the AP, set N = N -1, and repeat until no change.